# How do I turn each element in a list into a string with quotes

Tags: python, string, list, pycharm

I am using PyCharm IDE.

I frequently work with large data sets, and sometimes I have to iterate through each data.

For instance, I have a list

```
ticker_symbols = [500.SI, 502.SI, 504.SI, 505.SI, 508.SI, 510.SI, 519.SI...]
```

How do I automatically format each element into a string with quotes, i .e.

```
ticker_symbols = ['500.SI', '502.SI', '504.SI', '505.SI', '508.SI', '510.SI', '519.SI'...] ?
```

Is there a short-cut on PyCharm?

Comment: How about using "Find and Replace" with "regex" and use a macro to store it? I have done in other text editors and its quite handy to have it anywhere. See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do something like:

```
ticker_symbols = '[500.SI,502.SI,504.SI,505.SI,508.SI,510.SI,519.SI]'
print(ticker_symbols[1:-1].split(','))
```

Or like your string:

```
ticker_symbols = '[500.SI, 502.SI, 504.SI, 505.SI, 508.SI, 510.SI, 519.SI]'
print(ticker_symbols[1:-1].split(', '))
```

Both reproduce:

```
['500.SI', '502.SI', '504.SI', '505.SI', '508.SI', '510.SI', '519.SI']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
temp_list = ["'{}'".format(x) for x in ticker_symbols]
```

Result in:

```
['500.SI', '502.SI', '504.SI',...]
```

Comment: Possibly best of all is to just print that whole thing and then copy paste/output it into the file. That way if the list truly is massive it doesn't have to be done at runtime.

Comment: Any question can have many answers and the best of them is chosen based on conditions

Comment: Sorry, "best of all" was meant to say this was an extension to your answer, not "here is a better alternative". Perhaps not the best choice of phrase.

Comment: Thanks for adding extension to answer

Answer (score 0):

This will convert your list elements to strings`ticker_symbols=str(ticker_symbols[1:-1].split(', '))`